# Byte-compile org-babel code blocks when tangled

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I want to override `org-babel-tangle-file` to byte compile any org-babel code block where a `compile: t` flag is set in `header-args`. Here is the idea:

```
* Sample code block
  :PROPERTIES:
  :header-args: :tangle ~/code.el :compile t
  :END:

  #BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
  (insert "Hello world!")
  #END_SRC
```

and ideal, this would also work at the block level:

```
* Sample code block

  #BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle ~/code.el :compile t
  (insert "Hello world!")
  #END_SRC
```

and globally as well:

```
#+TITLE: Sample org file
#+PROPERTY: header-args :tangle "~/code.el" :compile t

* Sample code block

  #BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
  (insert "Hello world!")
  #END_SRC
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What would this header arg  mean for non-emacs-lisp code blocks? And for emacs-lisp, what stops you from doing a `byte-recompile-directory` in the directory where the tangled files live? If you want it done automatically, you can add an after-advice to `org-babel-tangle`. I just don't see why a header argument would be needed.

Comment: That's a good point – I had not considered other languages. Can you elaborate on your `after-advice` approach?

Comment: Basically, with `advice`, you wrap a function inside another which does something before (or after or around) the wrapped function. You can read about it in the [doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html#index-advising-functions-1006). For your first version, I'd advise (sic) you to use a hard-coded directory so there is no problem communicating it to `byte-recompile-directory`. If that proves doable and you find it agreeable, then you can worry about somehow extracting the directory from the source block and passing it to the recompile function.